# I keep getting a 404 error when trying run route.js in my API directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Project Structure:

[image]

I have a component that should call an API function but for some reason it seems as if the file is not found, I've made sure I've set up the directory correctly, and followed next.js project setup.

**CSVUploader.js:**

```
'use client'

// components/CSVUploader.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function CSVUploader() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        const response = await fetch('/api/route', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload and Process</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**route.js**

```
// pages/api/route.js
import { exec } from 'child_process';

export default async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // Assuming you're sending the CSV as text in the request body
        const csvData = req.body;

        // Save CSV data to a temporary file
        const tempFile = 'geofences_istak.csv';
        require('fs').writeFileSync(tempFile, csvData);

        // Run the Python script
        exec('python3 scripts/process_csv.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to process the file.' });
            }

            // Respond with the result or the processed file location
            res.status(200).json({ data: stdout });
        });
    } else {
        res.status(405).end();  // Method Not Allowed
    }
};
```

But the error I get is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `/api`. Please do not include `route` in the `api` path.

```
const response = await fetch('/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
});
```

Similar to how you don't call `/page` to render page.